# ReferenceError: Quill is not defined while unit testing

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, primeng, quill

I got  [this same issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/807) and i resolved it and working perfectly when i run the application.

But same issue am getting right now while run the unit test. am using karma and jasmine tool.

I have tried include quill.js file in karma.config.js fill as well.

```
  files: ['./node_modules/quill/quill.js',
          { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: true }
        ],
```

but still am facing the same issue.

Any idea to resolve this issue?

Comment: If you have included quill js files in **angular-cli.json**, you don't need to provide that in *karma.config.js*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have resolved this issue by using a flag with *ngIf

```
<div class="ui-grid-col-6" style="width:114%;" *ngIf="display">
                   <p-editor [(ngModel)]="printEmailCOC.MailBody" [style]="{'height':'250px'}"></p-editor>
               </div>
```

- I am assigning that flag to true while running that code via application
- I am assigning  set that flag to false while running that code via unit testing.

> So Now the p-editor DOM element does not render. And we don't care about the quill package while Unit Testing.

Answer (score 2):

I added `"node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js"` in angular.json file in scripts array

`"test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/scss/styles.scss"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ]
          }
        },`
 
restarted `ng test` and the component passed the test

Comment: Also, I had to add QuillModule to my imports in the *spec.ts file.